# How to adjust three div one left and other two right side in css-flex-float?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I want to set three div one left side and other two left side but `float: right;`  do not fix my problem. I am trying the flowing code.

```css
.container .A {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height: 80px;
    background: lightskyblue;
}

.container .B {
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    height: 80px;
    background:  lightgreen;
}

.container .C {
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    height: 80px;
    background: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="C">C </div>
</div>
```

I want to set the div according to following image. [image]

For Mobile view, I want to change the div like the following image
[image]

Comment: Use flex and mediaqueries.  It Will be much easier and without *side effects*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it using `flexbox` and `media queries`. I have used `order` property in media queries to change positions of boxes on small screen :)

**CODEPEN LINK:** https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/eYdQKgy

**FULL CODE:**

```css
.container{
  display:flex;
}

.container div{
  margin:1rem;
}
.container .A {
    width:100px;
    height: 80px;
    background: lightskyblue;
    margin-right:auto;
}

.container .B {
   
    width:100px;
    height: 80px;
    background:  lightgreen;
}

.container .C {
    width:100px;
    height: 80px;
    background: hotpink;
}

@media(max-width:768px){
  .container .C{
    order:-1;
    margin-right:auto;
  }
  .container .A{
     margin-right:1rem;
    
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="C">C </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is the **flex** solution.

You can swap blocks using the `order` rule.

Also, I added a **media query**.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    width: 100%;
}

.container .A {
    width:100px;
    height: 80px;
    background: lightskyblue;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.container .B {
    width:100px;
    height: 80px;
    background:  lightgreen;
}

.container .C {
    width:100px;
    height: 80px;
    background: hotpink;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .container .A {
    margin-right: unset;
    order: 2;
  }

  .container .B {
    order: 3;
  }

  .container .C {
    order: 1;
    margin-right: auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="A">A</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="C">C </div>
</div>
```

Comment: :Hi There. You answer is good and you were way faster than mine :) I think `order` property is needed only once that too on .box C only :) See my solution once ^^ !

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather, Each developer has his own point of view on the implementation of this or that functionality.

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather, Thank you for your solidarity :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found one solution.
Please try with this code.

```css
  .container .A {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    background: lightskyblue;
  }

  .container .B {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    background: lightgreen;
  }

  .container .C {
    float: right;
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    background: hotpink;
  }

  @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .container .A {
      float: right;
    }
    .container .C {
      float: left;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="C">C</div>
  <div class="B">B</div>
  <div class="A">A</div>
</div>
```

Best regards.